# No Internet access when second dial-up connection in Windows 7

Tags: tcp, modem

I have a dial-up connection set apart from my normal internet access. When I connect to that dial-up , I loose Internet access (from the 1st network). When the dial-up is not active, Internet works fine. I have disabled Use default gateway on remote network in IPv 4 config. Any guesses why this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below steps:

1. Go to Network & Sharing Center
2. Click on the menu Advanced
3. Click on Advanced Settings
4. Try changing the order of connections in the window.

Answer (score 0):

Your host uses a single physical interface for Internet access. Either its interface resides within the broadcast domain of *normal internet access* or the dial-up connection. When the host has dialed up, an IP address is assigned which most certainly is not in the same domain as one used by the normal access. Furthermore, it seems to me that your host does not run any special routing service to run both connections simultaneously.

Another explanation relies on the cabling between the phone socket and the modem. If the cable does not have a splitter built in, a dial up claims the whole line and DSL cannot synchronize. This varies due to regional designs.